# Where call apex api procedures

Tags: oracle, api

I'm learning now [Apex Api Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/toc.htm). But I can't understand where I can run this procedures for testing. I only have found that procedures from Apex_Item package, I can run from standard Sql Editor in select queries. For me it looks that procedures from Apex_Instance_Admin should be run from admin panel, but I can't find there any editor

Comment: http://apex.oracle.com request a free workspace there.

Comment: You haven't understand me. I have install apex on my computer. The question where inside apex I can test that procedures?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run any of the API packages from the SQL Editor, or from SQL*Plus (if you login with a user that has APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE).